# hay Fat32, thank you for pushing me over the edge into 5 digits

Tags: discussion

now with all this rep, i got "Access to Moderator tools".

so what good are "Moderator tools"?  can i kick someone's butt outa here?  throw my weight around?

what good is having rep if i can't make those with less rep shake in their boots?

Comment: I am afraid that [these](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) won't allow you to "kick someone's butt outa here" :) The main usage of them is to help moderators with running this site. You will have access to deleted questions, the review queue and off course deleting the questions.

Comment: @jojek We should "kick r b-j's but outa here" :-) JOKE! :-) Welcome to the 10k club, r b-j!

Comment: ahh, none of that looks like any fun, jojek.

Comment: hmm yes I saw you needed just a few clicks... :-) but how did you... ?

Comment: For me to know and you to find out. :-)